# How do I inflate a toolbar in PreferenceFragment?

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

In PreferenceFragment, the view is inflated like so

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

and not by creating a view object and inflating it. So now, if I want to implement a toolbar in my settings fragment, which extends PreferenceFragment, I need to do this:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

but without a view object, how am I supposed to use `findViewById`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use your activity to get the view by id.

```
getActivity().findViewById(...)
```

You can read more about getViewByid and activities' methods [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: Glad it was useful :)